# OpenGL glCreateProgram() always return 1 and erase previous programs

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering, shader

Using RAD Studio C++ Builder XE7 and OpenGL, I'm creating an application on which several TPanel objects are used as render target. Each of these panels use their own render context. With OpenGL Direct Mode, I'm able to draw a scene on each of them without problems.

Now I want to each scene have their own shader program. If only one panel in my app exploits a shader, all is running fine. However, as soon as I select a new render context, to generate and link a new program, the programs generated with the previous context seems to be erased, and the glCreateProgram() function returns the same identifiers as generated in the previous context, as if the new programs take the place of the existing ones.

I cannot figure out why OpenGL behaves this way, but this issue generates a serious confusion in my rendering. It seems that only the shader programs are concerned, all the other values belonging to a context seem conserved while I select another context. Should I save and restore my contexts every time I select another one? Somebody can explain what I'm doing wrong?

Here is a simplified code sample illustrating the issue I face. (I call a such function for each of my target panels)

```cpp
bool TMainForm::InitGL(HWND hWnd, HDC& hDC, HGLRC& hRC)
{
    // get the device context (DC)
    hDC = ::GetDC(hWnd);

    // failed to get device context?
    if (!hDC)
        return false;

    ::PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd =
    {
        sizeof(::PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),
        1,
        PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER,
        PFD_TYPE_RGBA,
        24,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        32,
        0,
        0,
        PFD_MAIN_PLANE,
        0,
        0,
        0,
    };

    // get best available pixel format
    const int pixelFormat = ::ChoosePixelFormat(hDC, &pfd);

    // set pixel format to use
    if (!::SetPixelFormat(hDC, pixelFormat, &pfd))
        return false;

    // create OpenGL render context
    hRC = wglCreateContext(hDC);

    // succeeded?
    if (!hRC)
        return false;

    // enable OpenGL render context
    if (!wglMakeCurrent(hDC, hRC))
        return false;

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

    // (re)initialize GLEW, as described here:
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35683334/call-glewinit-once-for-each-rendering-context-or-exactly-once-for-the-whole-app
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
        return false;

    GLuint programID = glCreateProgram();

    // here the returned programID is always equal to 1!!!
    ::OutputDebugString((L"==> Newly generated shader ID - " + ::IntToStr((int)programID)).c_str());
}
```

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every gl-context owns its objects, gl-programs included. See https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context

If you want to share among several contexts, you can set so at gl-context creation.

Comment: So if I understood, OpenGL REALLY deletes my programs every time I create and select a new context, right? What is the best practice in this case, should I generate a global program in a context I arbitrary consider as the "main" context, and share it with the entire app contexts? Or is there a way to declare a program by context, and keep it in memory whenever the context changes?

Comment: In fact I'm not sure I really understood this concept of contexts. My question can be asked in this way: how can I create separate render contexts, each of them containing a separate shader program, shared in an unique application?

Comment: The GPU driver does NOT delete a program until you tell it do it. Making current a context means that only objects for that context have action; the rest "sleep". If your windows have same features (color, depth, etc) then you can have an only context for all of them. If you decide to use several contexts, they can share some objects.

Comment: This is how I expected it to work. However, when I try to do it, the glCreateProgram() returns always the same ID, for example 1 in the code posted above, and for each call to glCreateProgram(), the previously registered one seems to be erased. If I call 2 times the above function (of course with different handles) I obtain 2 time 1 as ID. I also tried to initialize all the OpenGL contexts first in a function, then just call wglMakeCurrent() and glCreateProgram() for each initialized context, I gained the same result. So I do something wrong in my initialization, but what?

Comment: The IDs returned by `glCreateProgram()` (and buffers and objects...) are context-dependant. Two not-shared contexts may return the same program-ID. Try creating two programs in the same context (different IDs) and in different contexts (may return the same ID).

Comment: After recreating a complete example from scratch, I noticed that OpenGL behaves as described above by Ripi2, and may generate same IDs in different contexts, without the ones interfering with the others. The issue I face really happen in another part of my code. I found a way to workaround it, but I still not really understood what happened, unfortunately. But for sure that was not linked to a context mixup, as I was thinking first. Many thanks for the replies, which allowed me to advance in the understanding of OpenGL.